# How to integrate my python plugin with nagios

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu-14.04, haproxy, nagios

I have a python script written that hits a url to my application which is behind HAPROXY and returns the version of application.

I want to integrate this script/plugin with my nagios server and display the version information on nagios. It would solve two purposes that it would check the availability and also show the version info.

Appreciate any help.

Thanks,
Ankit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Edited to address comments*

To use a python script as a custom Nagios plugin, your script just needs to follow the [Nagios Plugin API](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/3/en/pluginapi.html).
The important thing is that your script exit with correct return code for the state it's reporting -- meaning your python script needs to exit with **return code 0** if the check is reporting that everything is **OK**.
Exit with **return code 2** to indicate a **CRITICAL** state.
You should also format the output of your script to conform with the [Plugin Output Spec](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/3/en/pluginapi.html)

Below is an example.  Please note that this is only for **EXAMPLE** purposes and probably **will not** work for your site unless your site just so happens to have the same div id as stackoverflow.com ;) *(Updated to include configurable URL parameter.)*

**check_version.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import re, sys, subprocess, shlex
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from optparse import OptionParser

def main():
    usage = "usage: %prog [options]"
    parser = OptionParser(usage)
    parser.add_option("-u", "--url",
                      action="store", dest="url",
                      help="URL of host to check version number of.")
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
    # Make warning and critical command line arguments mandatory.
    if options.url is None:
        print "Incorrect usage. URL is mandatory."
        parser.print_help()
        sys.exit(3)
    try:
        url = options.url
        curl_command = '/usr/bin/curl {url}'.format(url=url)
        args = shlex.split(curl_command)
        curl = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        (html_doc, err) = curl.communicate()
        if err:
            print "CRITICAL - ERROR connecting to url: %s | 'rev'='NA';;;;" % (str(err))
            sys.exit(2)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
        soup_svnrev = soup.find(id='svnrev')
        if soup_svnrev is None:
            print "CRITICAL - ERROR - Revision number could not be found on site! | 'rev'='NA';;;;"
            sys.exit(2)
        svnrev = soup_svnrev.get_text().strip()
        rev_num = svnrev.split()[1]
        print "OK. revision number = {rev_num} | 'rev_num'={rev_num};;;;".format(rev_num=rev_num)
        sys.exit(0)
    except Exception, e:
        print "CRITICAL - Unexpected error: %s | 'rev'='NA';;;;" % (str(e))
        sys.exit(2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

With a working Nagios plugin script, you just need to add it as [Nagios Command](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/3/en/objectdefinitions.html#command) and finally schedule its execution by defining a [Nagios Service](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/3/en/objectdefinitions.html#service) for it.

*Edit with example configuration*

Of course you need to configure Nagios with everything Nagios would need to execute a check.
Meaning that at minimum you need to define **host, service,** and **command definitions** in some Nagios configuration file that your Nagios installation knows about.
That may differ for each Nagios installation so here I'll use /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg as an ***example***, adding in the following:

**/usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg**

```
define host{
    host_name           stackoverflow
    alias               stackoverflow
    address             stackoverflow.com
    check_command           check-host-alive
    check_interval          5
    retry_interval          1
    max_check_attempts      5
    check_period            24x7
    process_perf_data       0
    retain_nonstatus_information    0
    contacts            nagiosadmin
    notification_interval       30
    notification_period     24x7
    notification_options        d,u,r
}

define service{
    host_name       stackoverflow
    service_description check_version
    check_command       check_version!http://stackoverflow.com
    max_check_attempts  5
    check_interval  5
    retry_interval  3
    check_period        24x7
    notification_interval   30
    notification_period 24x7
    notification_options    w,c,r
    contacts        nagiosadmin
}

define command{
    command_name    check_version
    command_line    /path/to/check_version.py -u "$ARG1$"
}
```

If there are no errors in the script, your script has "execute" permissions, and there are no errors in the configuration, you should be able to run a verification check on your main Nagios configuration file:

```
nagios -v /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg
```

Restart the Nagios server to reload the configuration:

```
service nagios restart
```

And your site version should be visible when you view the service details for the "check_version" service of the "stackoverflow" host.

Comment: My python script is just the same as yours however, it takes the url as input because I need to check the status for different apps on different instances behind HAPROXY based on url (for e.g. https://abc-prod.mydomain.com/APP/aboutme). Script returns the application version information.
Instances are in VPC (AWS) and HAPROXY is the only way from outside so I can't use direct IP of instances to monitor from nagios server.
So what I need from nagios:
1. To feed the URL as parameter to my python script.
2. Display the version information on nagios dashboard.

Comment: Edited example script to include url parameter.

Comment: Perfectly explained, it worked as I wanted!
Thanks a lot!